# Mapping Un-Named Stored Procedure columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_MoodTester]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Id, 
           count(Id)  // Un-named, auto named to Column1 in entity model
    FROM Behaviors
    WHERE Id = 1
    GROUP by Id
END
```

When I call this stored procedure from application like this

```
var aa = context.sp_MoodTester().ToList();
```

I get an exception

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'RelativityModel.sp_MoodTester_Result'. A member of the type,
>   'Column1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader
>   with the same name.

Then I tried an other way, like

I created a model like

```
public class ModelClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Column1 { get; set; }
}
```

and tried this way

```
var obj = context.Database.SqlQuery<ModelClass>("sp_MoodTester").ToList();
```

it returns an object but with null column 'Column1' while there is a value '1' returning from database for this column.

[image]

My question is how can I get this value as I am unable to access database to modify the stored procedure?

I am still unable to solve this issue.

Comment: You should change your procedure and give the column a name. Also, you might want to look at this. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: I mentioned above that I can't change stored procedure, as database is not in my access. The stored proc above is a sample stored proc.

Comment: The column has no name. I don't know there is much you can do other than go find the dummy who wrote that proc and punch them for not giving an aggregate column a name.

Comment: I can't travel thousands of miles just to punch him, even if assured that he will not reply :)

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of your mapping details of the stored srocedure to the complex type ?

Answer (score -2):

Give the count column a name:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_MoodTester]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Id, 
           count(Id) as 'theCount'
    FROM Impacts
    where Id = 1
    GROUP by Id
END
```